# GWT RPC. Share RPC service bwtween two modules

Tags: java, gwt

I haven an application with 2 GWT-modules (`.gwt.xml`). I want to share between them *one* RPC service. But modules have different names, so first module calls RPC service from

`FIRSTModuleName/relativepath`  (and it works)

but second module try to call it from

`SECONDModuleName/relativepath` (it doesn't work, because path is incorrect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either map your `RemoteserviceServlet` to both URLs (by far the simplest solution), or you can change your client-side code to make both modules call the same URL.

For the latter, don't use `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` but instead cast your service *async* to [`ServiceDefTarget`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/ServiceDefTarget.html) and call `setServiceEntryPoint` with the URL you want to use (`@RemoteServiceRelativePath` is only a shortcut to have `setServiceEntryPoint` called automatically with `GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + relativePath`).
I believe you could also use a `../`-style URL in your `@RemoteServiceRelativePath`.

Answer (score 1):

And for production don't forget to added a second servlet mapping entry to the web.xml. You can have a servlet listening to as many URLs as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to place the shared RPC methods into a common base class.